# Looking for a way to generate and show a Quote PDF in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pdf, quote

My org has a number of Quote templates. In Classic we have created a custom JS button that automatically selects the proper template, generates the Quote PDF and pops up the generated PDF along with some custom buttons. I probably found the code to do this on StackExchange.

Of course, in Lightning this does not work anymore. [This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221742/programmatically-generate-quote-pdf-in-lightning-component-apex-controller) tells me how to generate the Quote PDF from an action in Lightning. But it stops there. How can I both generate and show a Quote PDF, preferably using the same library as Lightning itself is using?

The Classic JS code uses a JS library called QuotePDFPreview, but I can't find any information about it.